# Django model manytomany field count occurrence

Tags: python, django, django-models

models.py

```
class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, unique=True)
    count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True) # This should be the occurrence count in ETF

class ETF(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField() 
    region = models.ManyToManyField(Region, blank=True)
```

Example: If there is 100 ETF objects in ETF model have U.S.A. as region, then count field in U.S.A. object in Region model should be 100.

How do I automatically update the count field in Region Model everytime there are changes in the database? Sorry if there is duplicate question,

I just can't find the keywords to search for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to count the number of `ETF`s for a `Region`, you can calculate that *when necessary* with [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Region.objects.annotate(
    count_etf=Count('etf')
)
```

The `Region`s that arise from *this* queryset will have an extra attribute `.count_etf` that contains the number of related `ETF` objects for that `Region`.

If an `ETF` is linked to *multiple* `Region`s, than all these regions will count that as one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!